# Cloudflare Load Balancer to AWS Application Load Balancer to Spring Cloud Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, gateway, cloudflare

I'm trying to build a pretty large microservices infrastructure with Amazon, Spring Cloud Gateway and Eureka.

I am wondering, would it be something well done if we get Cloudflare Load Balancer to point to two different AWS Application Load Balancer URLs and then those AWS ALB URLs go to the Spring Cloud Gateway and then they connect to microservices.

The idea of doing this is being able to connect to 2 different Spring Cloud Gateways as the AWS ALB can only redirect to once instance (gateway). By creating two ALB entries I could go to two different gateways and use Cloudflare as the Load Balancer to distribute load 50/50 (weight based).

Any ideas, comments or suggestions?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by this: *"the AWS ALB can only redirect to once instance (gateway)."*  ALB is typically used to *forward* traffic (not *redirect* traffic) and one ALB can have a large number of instances behind it, with each instance handling approximately 1/n of the traffic offered, as long as the instances are in the same AWS region.

Comment: I believe I wrote that wrong, one ALB can forward one port to one instance but not multiple instance doing something such as round robin, weighted forward, etc. I'm hoping to do that in order to forward traffic to two Spring Cloud Gateways.

Comment: That also isn't accurate.  ALB can send traffic round-robin to multiple target instances from the same listener port on the balancer, by adding multiple instances to a single target group.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-target-groups.html